# How to search an array and get back it's "=>" value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an input:

```
$url = $params[0];
```

I have an array:

```
$dictionary = array(
    "stock" => 1,
    "user" => 2,
    "zone" => 3);
```

How can I use the input to search the left values of this array (stock, user, zone, etc.) and get back the value on the right (1, 2, 3, etc.)?

Comment: you mean... `$dictionary['stock']`? ...and if `$url` is stock or user or whatever... `$dictionary[$url]` would return the number associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, just access it like this

```
$dictionary[$url]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this $url variable as a key to get the => value associated with it.

```html
 $dictionary = array(
            "stock" => 1,
            "user" => 2,
            "zone" =>3);

$url = $params[0]; 

$yourDesiredValue = $dictionary[$url];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are searching, you will want to check if the value (I presume `$url`) is set within the array and return it if true.

```
$value = false;
if (isset($dictionary[$url])) {
  $value = $dictionary[$url];
}
```

Then, `$value` will be `false` if the search fails, but contain the number if the search is successful.